# Selecting div's href's and submitting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I have this code in my html:

```
<div id="div1">
<a href="a"> Apple </a>
<a href="b"> Orange </a>
<a href="c"> Lemon </a>
<a href="d"> Banana </a>
</div>

<form action=" ">
<input type="text" name="q" id="input1" >
</form>
```

When ever I click anything in the div1 is set to the input thanks to [@alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31671/alex)

Is it possible to submit the form too though?

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
$('#div1 > a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#input1').val($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I have a fiddle of how it looks like. http://jsfiddle.net/FCHpn/

Comment: What is the reason for using jQuery for this scenario?

Comment: The part `$(this).attr('href')` is several dozen (perhaps many more) function calls and can be replaced by a simple property access: `this.href`.

Comment: How about using plain form with radiobuttons? Add some CSS and done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will submit the form which `#input1` sits in.

```
$('#div1 > a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#input1').val($(this).attr('href')).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: The input has a form attribute that is the form it belongs to. Consider: `var el=$('#input1')[0]; el.value=this.href; el.form.submit();` and save a gazillion functions calls.

Answer (score 2):

To submit the form you just have to call `.submit()` on the form element. I would give the form an id and then call something like

```
$("#formid").submit();
```